# How can display the last 6 characters in JSX using ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to JavaScript and I learnt how to use JSX to render HTML code. I am passing a string in the Span element in HTML however I want only the last 6 characters of the information to show up on the webpage. So I am trying to use Ellipsis property to do but the number of characters is not reducing. I need the data.id to be only the last 6 characters of the passed string. How can I do this? Can I do this using the ellipsis property or should I use some JavaScript function inside the JSX? I am not sure why the CSS is not working. Can anyone please help?

```css
.branchText {
  color: var(--secondaryHeader);
  max-width: calc(100% - 16px);
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span className={styles.branchInfoWrapper}>
                      <span className={styles.branchName}>Master :</span>
                      <span
                        className={classNames(styles.branchText)}
                        ellipsisText
                        title={data.get('id')}
                      >
                        {data.get('id')}
                      </span>
                    </span>
```

data.id is what I need to display next to the Master: text. It needs to be only the last 6 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can show only 6 last characters with CSS, it's normally based on width, so you can use JavaScript:

This will only show last 6 characters:

```
<span>
  {data.get('id').substr(data.get('id').length - 6)}
</span>
```

Using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) if statement, it will add ellipsis if id has more than 6 characters.

```
<span>
  {data.get('id').length > 6 ? "..." + data.get('id').substr(data.get('id').length - 6) : data.get('id')}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `npm i react-lines-ellipsis --save` and use like this

```
import LinesEllipsis from 'react-lines-ellipsis'

<LinesEllipsis
   text='long long text'
   maxLine='3'
   ellipsis='...'
   trimRight
   basedOn='letters'
/>
```